# Programmatically reading xml file from JBoss AS 7.x Modules folder

Tags: java, xml, jboss, jboss7.x

I know how to read properties file programmatically from JBoss AS 7.x Modules folder.

**Is It possible to read .xml files from JBoss AS 7.x Modules folder?**
If It is possible then **how can It be done** or please refer me to any documentation page.

**What have I done myself?**

I have searched on internet but found only about loading jars and properties file from Module folder.

I think that there can be other ways to do it but I am curious to know **is there any way that xml file can be read like properties file?** or Modules folder are **only** used for loading jars and properties file?

Comment: if you simply want to read some xml-files, you can do it easily with sax - tell me if you need help with that...

Comment: @MartinFrank: I knew how to read xml files. But I am curious to know is there any way that xml files can be read from modules folder like properties file are read?

Comment: ok, now i understand your question... sorry, then i can not be helpful :-( i know only of properties and bundles which can do that...